# Set up dependency resolution properly

Tags: c#, .net, nuget

I have a c# mvc project (mvc) which depends on a self created dll (dll) and this self created dll depends on some 3rd party dlls (3rd). When I build the mvc project, it triggers the build of the dll as expected but when I try to check the page in a browser getting an error message that the 3rd party dlls cannot be found in the mvc/bin directory (and in the other default places). First question if it is normal that the compiler triest to find these dependencies in mvc/bin instead of `dll/bin`? I mean it's the dll which depends on them.

The other question is that i tried to solve the problem by copy all the dependencies into `mvc/packages` and set up hintpath in .csproj file but when I execute `nuget restore` it fetches the 3rd party dlls from nuget repo. How can I tell to nuget that I have these dlls in a directory already? Guess I have to specify in in the .csproj file, but wasn't able to find how.

**update:**
I'm working with vscode so any right click magic VS does is unrelated here.

Comment: what is `dll/bin`? The resolving of assemblies is clearly documented. First loader searches within the path where the current assembly is located. So dependencies for mvc clearly are searched within mvc/bin.

Comment: @HimBromBeere so you mean that if A depends on B and B depends on C the A/bin should contain both B.dll and C.dll, right? In that case how should I tell to msbuild to move C.dll to A/bin because seems that in my case this is the step which is missing.